# with BOTO3 , how can I filter and describe snapshots by date only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fetch snapshot details name as filter. But I am not able to list the snaps taken on perticular date. as an example I am giving input as date 2019-08-05 ( YYYY-MM-DD format. I want to list down all snaps taken on 2019-08-05 . Is there any way I can us the date filed only with snapshot_describe with filters option?

Here is the code what I tried so far.............`

```
import boto3
import datetime
snapdate = input("please Enter the date you want to restore the data from 
in YYYY-DD-MM format :")
#date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(snapdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
#print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance = boto3.resource('ec2')
snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values': 
['aws-test-1']}])['Snapshots']
#print(snapshots)
for snap in snapshots:
    snap_ids = snap['SnapshotId']
    snap_date = snap['StartTime']
    print(snap_ids, snap_date)
```

the above code is giving the output as ...

```
please Enter the date you want to restore the data from in YYYY-DD-MM 
format :2019-08-05 snap-03e939df606c58363 2019-08-09   
07:02:57.302000+00:00 snap-01d4f7900101f05c4 2019-08-05 
12:17:20.958000+00:00 snap-0df64539cd03478cf 2019-08-05 
12:38:53.865000+00:00 snap-067098d01753e4d4b 2019-08-09 
07:02:13.010000+00:00 snap-03bfb7fb2bf6711fe 2019-08-09    
07:02:35.487000+00:00 Now,
```

I want to list the snaps only which has been taken on : 2019-08-05. Any guidance would be a great help please

Comment: the above code is giving the output as ...
please Enter the date you want to restore the data from in YYYY-DD-MM format :2019-08-05
snap-03e939df606c58363 2019-08-09 07:02:57.302000+00:00
snap-01d4f7900101f05c4 2019-08-05 12:17:20.958000+00:00
snap-0df64539cd03478cf 2019-08-05 12:38:53.865000+00:00
snap-067098d01753e4d4b 2019-08-09 07:02:13.010000+00:00
snap-03bfb7fb2bf6711fe 2019-08-09 07:02:35.487000+00:00

Now, I want to list the snaps only which has been taken on : 2019-08-05. Any guidance would be a great help please

Comment: Edit your question adding what you commented, or, if the platform doesn't allow you to, tell so moderation can do it on behalf of you.

Comment: added users question update that he has commented bellow and added python tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the filter with a specific date, then you also have to know the exact start-time. In general, it is really hard. So, I listed the snapshots without start-time filter and give the condition before print.

```
import boto3
import datetime
snapdate = '2019-08-01'

client = boto3.client('ec2')

isnext = None
while True:
    if isnext:
        response = client.describe_snapshots(NextToken = isnext)
    else:
        response = client.describe_snapshots()

    snapshots = response['Snapshots']

    for snap in snapshots:
        snap_ids = snap['SnapshotId']
        snap_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(snap['StartTime'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        if snapdate == snap_date: print(snap_ids, snap_date)

    try:
        isnext = response['NextToken']
    except KeyError:
        break
```

The result is

```
snap-0...7e22b0790 2019-08-01
snap-0...6b264cf98 2019-08-01
snap-0...04d0b49e1 2019-08-01
snap-0...a87e38659 2019-08-01
snap-0...5278ace48 2019-08-01
snap-0...c5487f9ae 2019-08-01
snap-0...1ff14c425 2019-08-01
snap-0...20182eff6 2019-08-01
snap-0...9b33107f5 2019-08-01
snap-0...351d539e1 2019-08-01
snap-0...8c3fa74d9 2019-08-01
snap-0...5c1bb93e6 2019-08-01
snap-0...5ed53c17c 2019-08-01
```

**Modified**

I have added the NextToken treatment for if you have a lot of snapshots.

Comment: Hi Lamanus, this helps alot. I have completed my final script of snapshot restore operation per Ec2 by date/time . Many Thanks :-)